# Chain Rule on Vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let's suppose I have a smooth vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I have a integral curve of $X$: $$\gamma^x_m(t):t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, \qquad \gamma^x_m (0)=m.$$

**I want to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}X(\gamma^x_m(t))$.**

Intuitively I would use the "chain rule" and do something like this: $\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}X(\gamma^x_m(t))=\frac{d}{d \gamma^x_m} X(\gamma^x_m(t))\frac{d}{dt}\gamma^x_m(t)_{|t=0}$.

**How can I justify this?** I've browsed through my literature and can't find anything useful.

**Is $\frac{d}{d \gamma^x_m} X(\gamma^x_m(t))$ maybe equal to the pushforward of $X$ given by a Jacobian, since we have $X$ on  $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?**

**How can my "chain rule" be justified when $X$ is defined on some (general) smooth manifold, instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?**

[Related: Vector Field Flow Chain Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460506/vector-field-flow-chain-rule)

Comment: What is your definition of $\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0}$ of a vector field (in particular when it is defined on a smooth manifold generally)?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt} $ relates to the derivative with respect to the parameter $t$, that parametrizes the integral curve, as stated above.

Comment: Yes, my question is how you are defining the derivative in this case. In the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can think of the vector field $X$ as function $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, in which case $X\circ\gamma$ is a function $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and has a derivative in the sense of calculus. But in general, $X$ is a section $M\rightarrow TM$, so $X\circ\gamma$ is a map $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow TM$. How do you define "the derivative at $0$" of this map. The image of the tangent vector $\frac{d}{dt}\vert_0$ under the differential at $0$?

Comment: Just use the definition of integral curve, and the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is parallelizable.

Comment: You'd be far better off writing $(f\circ g)'(t) = Df(g(t))g'(t)$, rather than using the horrid beginning calculus Leibniz notation and writing $d/d\gamma^x_m$, whatever that means. Here $Df(a):\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is the derivative map or matrix. Differentiate $X$ as a map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Thorgott I think that $X$ is meant as a section $M \rightarrow TM$ and $M=\mathbb{R}^n$. But I'm also looking for an explanation in the case where $M$ doesn't necessarily equal $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right $\frac{d}{d \gamma^x_m}$ doesn't mean anything, I just wrote it like that for illustration purposes. In the case $f$ is a vector field $X$ does $Df$ equal the pushforward of $f$ (or $X$) ? Is $(f\circ g)'(t)=D f(g(t))g'$  true also when $f$ is a vector field defined on smooth manifold $\neq \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Could you please maybe state a theorem or give a reference?